# Sort 2D array according to 1D array

Tags: c#, sorting

I need help with sorting. I have table of numbers stored as Int32[,] array

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 6 
9 10 11 12 7 
13 14 15 16 8
```

and I need to sort it (lines not columns) according to another array for example `1 8 3 2`.

Length of second array and number of lines in first always match. I know you can use `Array.Sort(firstArray, secondArray);` to sort first array and change second so indexes matches but that works only if second array is 1D.

Can anyone help? I know you can create comparator but how to create it for this case? 
Thanks for responses in advance...

PS: I tried to find solutions here, nothing really helped and I have been trying for a while now...

Comment: `Array.Sort` will likely work if you convert your 2D array to a jagged array (array of arrays).

Comment: Never heard of jagged arrays in C# i will look it up. Thanks!

Comment: This is confusing.  Can you provide an example of the sorted result?

Comment: @Therian is array of array